# Can I inspect the proptypes of react component class if given an instance?

Tags: reactjs, introspection

I'd love to access the propTypes of a class, e.g.

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    text: React.PropTypes.string,
    href: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  ...
})

...

var ButtonPropTypes = Button.propTypes
```

I'd expect to see something along the lines of

```
{ text: function(){...}, href: function(){...} }
```

But instead I get `undefined`. What am I doing wrong, and how can I get at the proptypes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the proptypes statically as you are doing in your code. I put an example on jsfiddle and you can should be able to see the proptypes being printed in the console (they are functions)

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
          testing: 'default value'
        };
    },
    propTypes: {
        testing: React.PropTypes.string
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>        
                <div>{this.props.name}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));

console.log(Hello.propTypes)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fj7ax0qr/

Comment: Yep! I was foolishly attempting to access the proptypes on a class that didn't have any proptypes set! Thanks. :D