# How do I get an updated list of props that a component accepts?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the latest version of material-ui and am trying to find out what props a component, `AppBar` in this example, will accept. I've read the Component API for it [here](https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/#props) and there are only 4 props that are listed, however, props that worked on older versions of material-ui work on them too (i.e `onTitleClick`). I've checked the source code [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/AppBar/AppBar.js) and these props are passed along via the `...spread` operator, so there is no PropType validation for them. Without referring to extremely outdated documentation, how can I get a list of valid props?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I inspect the proptypes of react component class if given an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110766/can-i-inspect-the-proptypes-of-react-component-class-if-given-an-instance)

Answer (score 0):

The Appbar component has these four props you mentionned plus the props of the Paper component (it is mentionned at the end of the AppBar props documentation)

All other props are spread to the root element (it is also mentionned in the Paper props documentation).

- AppBar : https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/#props
- Paper : https://material-ui.com/api/paper/#props

`onTitleClick` typically is a **custom prop in your code** that is spread to the root element. It is not part of the AppBar or Paper props.

If you want validation for your props that are passed trought Material-UI components, you should do it in your code with PropTypes or TypeScript...